# App engine cron tasks return Error 204

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Starting this morning, I've been getting this error message in the logs for all taskqueue calls. The message is "A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request, causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)".  I haven't updated the app in a while and it used to work fine.  Can someone point out what this error means.

Thanks

app.yaml

```
application: appid
version: 1-05
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

- url: /worker.php
  script: tasks/worker.php
  login: admin

- url: /new_req
  script: tasks/Fetch/requestAmazonOrders.php
  login: admin
```

cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: new xml orders file requests
  url: /new_req
  schedule: every 7 hours from 04:55 to 19:30
  timezone: Europe/London
```

requestAmazonOrders.php

```
   use google\appengine\api\taskqueue\PushTask;


   try {

       $dt = new DateTime();
       $dt_now = new DateTime();

       $times = array(
           'a-start' => $dt->sub(new DateInterval('P90D'))->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'),
           'a-end' => $dt->add(new DateInterval('P30D'))->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'),
           'b-start' => $dt->add(new DateInterval('P0DT30S'))->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'),
           'b-end' => $dt->add(new DateInterval('P30D'))->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'),
           'c-start' => $dt->add(new DateInterval('P0DT30S'))->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'),
           'c-end' => $dt_now->sub(new DateInterval('P0DT2M'))->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s')
       );
       foreach (array('a', 'b', 'c') as $stage) {
           $params = array(
               'action' => 'NewReportRequest',
               'stage' => $stage,
               'times' => $times
           );
           $task = new PushTask('/worker.php', $params);
           $task_name = $task->add('Secondary');
           syslog(LOG_INFO, "NewReportRequest(FlatFile): stage: $stage. $task_name");
       }
       return;

   } catch (Exception $ex) {

       syslog(LOG_ERR, $ex->getLine() . PHP_EOL . $ex->getFile() . PHP_EOL . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL . $ex->getTraceAsString());
       return;

   }
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Added what I think is relevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I generally encountered this same error whenever my task take more than 10 min and user request take more than 1 min.this time out is different for different scaling type as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/taskqueue/overview-push#task_deadlines).

Comment: Thanks for replying, but no that is not the cause. The tasks usually run well within the 10 mins limit. The problem is not with the task execution; the error is given when cron runs the task (when /new_req is called).  Another thing to note is that it happens randomly.  Today, there's only two occurrences of this error and handlers that are not related to cron, so I'm starting to think this has to do with my app.yaml.